# Считывание их файла, InputMismatchException

Tags: java, строки, файлы, scanner

Не удается прочитать файл. Программа палает с `InputMismatchException`на 4 строке файла. При том, что 3 и 4 строки идентичны.
В родительском классе есть конструктор:

```
public Object(Scanner sc){
    this.POINT = sc.next();
    this.name = sc.next();
    this.price = sc.nextInt();  // Ругается на эту строку в коде
    this.number = sc.nextInt();
}
```

А два дочерних содержат следующие:

```
public ChildObject1(Scanner sc) {
    super(sc);
    this.valueInt = sc.nextInt();
}
```

и, соответственно

```
public ChildObject2(Scanner sc) {
    super(sc);
    this.valueDouble = sc.nextDouble();
}
```

Я пытаюсь считать файл следующим образом:

```
Scanner sc = null;
try {
    sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("src/file.txt"));
    sc.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    int i = 0;

    Object[] object= new Object[6];
    while (sc.hasNext()){
        object[i] = new Object(sc);
        i++;
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("Input file is not found");
} finally {
    if(sc != null) {
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

И, собственно, сам файл:

```
Point1 Bla 2500 5
Point1 Bla 2500 3
Point2 Bla 2500 11 400
Point2 Bla 2500 13 200
Point3 Bla 2500 7 8,5
Point3 Bla 2500 6 5,2
```

Comment: Очевидно, что у вас nextint() попадает на текст, который нельзя привести к int. Посмотрите в отладчике на каком тексте спотыкается программа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, я не очень понял как у вас связан конструктор `new Array(sc)`, который вызывается в основном коде, с тремя конструкторами, которые приведены выше.
Судя по всему у вас по факту вызывается первый конструктор всегда, который `Object(Scanner sc)`, что при этом происходит:

на 3 вызове, на строке

> Point2 Bla 2500 11 400

```
this.POINT = sc.next(); //Point2
this.name = sc.next(); //Bla
this.price = sc.nextInt();  //2500
this.number = sc.nextInt(); //11
```

Всё, далее, вы думаете что вы читаете уже 4 строку, но по факту у вас ещё не дочитано `400` из третьей, происходит новый вызов конструктора, где и происходит ваша ошибка:

```
this.POINT = sc.next(); //400 из третьей строки
this.name = sc.next(); //Point2 из четвертой
this.price = sc.nextInt(); //Bla это не число, InputMismatchException,             
                           //всё верно, ваш код делает ровно то, 
                           //что вы написали
```

Это можно легко было увидеть, воспользовавшись дебаггером

Comment: Но как же полифморфизм и позднее связывание? Разве java конструкторы не должны были вызываться сами в зависимости от количества элементов в строке?

Comment: Где полиморфизм? Покажите ваш конструктор `Array`, его в вопросе нет.

Comment: в примере просто не так назвал его, исправил

Comment: В таком случае, полиморфизма никакого нет, происходит ровно то, что вы написали в коде